# Entity Framework - IList<T> property allowing "Others" Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

In a large HTML Form that I am developing, some of the fields are lists of data (reference data stored in the database).

there is always "Others" and a Textbox to enter a value in case there is no match in the list.

How shall I treat the values inside the Textbox? They won't have an ID to keep a reference to their record on the main entity.

How shall I store them?

Thank you

Comment: what? show code

Comment: When you have value in "Others" textbox (which means user could enter a  value which is not in the dropdown),  - 1. save the value from the textbox  to database first and then do the processing OR 2. if you have a main entity associated with it, the assign a new instance of your navigational property so that when you save the main entity, the child entry (the value in others textbox) will get added to the corresponding table.

Comment: code helps other understand what you are trying to achieve. I.e use assuming i understand, use a ViewModel to capture the detail. Process at the same time so i figure (2) but again its assuming i understand what you want. By the sounds of it, you have a list, and other properties, but the other properties are not mapped to any backing field currently. My suggestion post code so we can see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks @Developer, you understood my problem. I could save directly to database but I thought maybe someone has to review the data first, if any new entities need to be created they will create them and fix the data accordingly. Because when it comes to reporting it is important to have the data well connected with IDs rather than text.

Comment: Bil - as @Seabizkit said, it would be easy if you could put some code. And re:_to have the data well connected with IDs rather than text_ - you should always connect it with ID, I never meant to have the loose relation. You should probably give more clarity on the problem statement.

Comment: Thanks @Developer. I still don't have a code for this. I was checking my requirements and wondering how to do so that's why I posted here. Usually I would link to IDs, but still, this is a weird requirement, based on some values selected I need to show/hide other controls. I will share my findings by code once I reach that level.